# Magento observer - after/before order place

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In my website there is a product having qty as 500 (For Example), if a user ordered 600 qty the payment must process for available and remaining 100 qty must get paid after the stock avail. At present user can only pay for 500 qty.

1. Can anybody help to update the qty to 600 after placing an order programmatically? So that admin can manage invoice/shipment for first 500 qty and after user pay for the 100 again invoice/shipment.
2. Any other option to manage this?

Current observer code (not working):

```
public function myfucn($observer){
    $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $id = '40'; 
    $qty = 600; 
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);}
```

Config.xml

```
<modules>
        <Ajt_PlaceOrder>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ajt_PlaceOrder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <placeprder>
                <class>PlaceOrder_Model</class>
            </placeprder>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <ajt_placeorder_model_observer>
                        <class>Ajt_PlaceOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>mymethod</method>
                    </ajt_placeorder_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
```

The above observer code im trying is to add product to cart. But if you have solution to update the qty of already existed item at cart before place an order please guide me.

Comment: Can you please share your config.xml file and more code if possible?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. 
- You want to execute a method(observer) before any order get placed
- Then you want to update that product quantity with the order quantity ??

Can you please elaborate if anything is missing ?

Comment: @PRASHANTBADERIYA yes i want to execute the method in observer which updates that order quantity before or after the order getting place thats it..Thanks for your response